# Matlab oop - Clearing object from memory does not call 'delete' method as expected

Tags: matlab, oop

### Context

I created two similar `PrimarySettings` and `SecondarySettings` handle classes in matlab to store settings of my own and was willing to group both of them in a bigger `AllSettings` class for convenience.

All classes have a `PropertyChanged` event to monitor for settings modifications.

The code for all classes can be visualized from [here](https://gist.github.com/CitizenInsane/d4f3ff43746cd1dce54f/a0a9f50005fe1a7ddb3589b5eebbb319476f958f).

### Problem

When I test `PrimarySettings` and `SecondarySettings` classes to check if their are effectively calling their `delete` method when all instances are no longer referenced in the code I have no issue:

```
>> ps = PrimarySettings();
>> clear ps;
Destroying PrimarySettings. 

>> ss = secondarySettings();
>> clear ss;
Destroying SecondarySettings.
```

The same when I test for proper event notifications:

```
>> as = AllSettings();
>> as.PrimarySettings.Titi = 12;
Property 'PrimarySettings.Titi' modified.
```

The problem is only with the `AllSettings` class for which `delete` method is never called at all:

```
>> as = AllSettings();
>> clear as;
!!!!!! here delete method is not called !!!!!
```

The object is still in memory while it is no longer referenced. This can be tested like this:

```
>> clear classes
Warning: Objects of 'SecondarySettings' class exist.  Cannot clear this class or any of its superclasses. 
Warning: Objects of 'PrimarySettings' class exist.  Cannot clear this class or any of its superclasses. 
Warning: Objects of 'AllSettings' class exist.  Cannot clear this class or any of its superclasses.
```

### Investigations

The problem seems linked to the way I am attaching the `PropertyChanged` event (the listener is probably still alive).

Unfortunately I truly don't understand why. Indeed, the code for attaching to events is very similar in all the classes I created.

`PrimarySettings` and `SecondarySettings`:

```
for idx = 1:propCount;
    listener = addlistener(obj, meta.PropertyList(idx).Name, 'PostSet', @obj.onPropertyChanged);
    listener.Recursive = true;
end
```

`AllSettings`:

```
for idx = 1:propCount;                
    propName = meta.PropertyList(idx).Name;
    listener = addlistener(obj, propName, 'PostSet', @obj.onPropertyChanged);
    listener.Recursive = true;
    listener = addlistener(obj.(propName), 'PropertyChanged', @obj.onSubPropertyChanged);
    listener.Recursive = true;
 end
```

NB: If I comment the second listener (i.e. `onSubPropertyChanged`) then the `AllSettings` class works as expected!

### Question

What's wrong with the deletion of `AllSettings` objects ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need a specific diagnosis of the issue, I'm afraid you'll need to post more code, so we can trace through what's going on exactly.

But I would expect that the issue is that one of your listeners is storing a reference to another of your objects in a way that you're not expecting, so it's not getting destroyed when you call `clear`.

To help you diagnose things further, note that there are two ways to create listeners:

1. Using `addlistener`, which ties the listener's lifecycle to the object that is the source of the event.
2. Constructing the listener directly using `event.listener`, where the listener exists only while it is in scope, and is not tied to the event-generating object's existence.

For more information, see the section "Ways to create listeners" in this documentation page on [Events and Listeners — Syntax and Techniques](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/matlab_oop/events-and-listeners--syntax-and-techniques.html).

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I will try using `event.listener` asap as I also think the listener is keeping the source alive. By the way, what do you mean by posting more code (sources for all classes is available [here](https://gist.github.com/CitizenInsane/d4f3ff43746cd1dce54f)) ?

Comment: @CitizenInsane Sorry, I didn't notice that link.

Comment: Great! Using `weakListener = event.listener(...)` syntax instead of `tiedListener = addlistener(...)` one solved the issue ([link](https://gist.github.com/CitizenInsane/d4f3ff43746cd1dce54f) to updated code). Thanks a lot.